# retrieve last successful build in visual studio vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

in visual studio 2013 vb.net coding, when you click 'Start' and it gives you a popup message saying that it contains errors would you like to run the last successful build?

How can I really get back the code of the last successful build because I have done several changes and I really want the old runnable build back.

I really appreciate all the help I can get.
thanks in advance!

Comment: Best advice is to use a form of source control such as Team Foundation or similar tool. Even zipping up a backup and giving zip file names versions in them is better than no backups. When dealing with source control tools one can revert back to earlier versions.

Answer (score 1):

As Karen advised, if your code isnt under version control, and you dont have backups (or undo history), then the code is gone.

One option, if you are desperate to see the content of the assembly, may be to reflect it.  This is the process of turning the assembly from IL back in to source.  The code that is produced will not be a mirror image of the original, as it will have been optimized/shuffled by the compiler, but it is often enough.  If you are interested check out [dnSpy](https://github.com/0xd4d/dnSpy/releases).